# Hiding iAds programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Currently I am showing iAds in my app.They are working fine.Now, I want to hide the iAds based on some conditions in code.

What I am using is

```
ADBannerView *bannr= (ADBannerView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

bannr.hidden = YES;

bannr.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

iAds get hidden.But when i press the area where iAd is supposed to be.Advertisement details window popup

Answer (score 0):

With my iAds I transition them on or off screen after the relevant callbacks are received by it's delegate.

It works for me fine.

Hope this helps
Good Luck,

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I really didnt understood what you meant.I think you are not clear what I mean, I want ads view to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Since `ADBannerView` is a subclass of `UIView` you should be able to remove it using `removeFromSuperview`.

```
[bannr removeFromSuperview];
```

It doesn't explain why you still can interact with the hidden view but you should be able to keep going.

#### Update

Alternative solution: If the ad gets triggered even when hidden you can perhaps try this in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
  if (banner.isHidden) {
    return NO;
  }
  
  // Business as usual
}
```

Comment: But Robert I dont want to remove, just hide

Comment: This is just a workaround since there seems to be a problem with hiding an `ADBannerView`. When you want to show it again you can just add it back in.